# How to bind the local endpoint to a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, local, endpoint

I have the following code where I'm trying to send a packet to a specific client by changing the endpoint of the socket manually and I'm not sure how to configure the socket to use the `async_write` function to send the packet. Lines 44-47 are used to try solving the problem within the boost async server example (modified).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
      std::cout<<"start(): "<<std::endl;
          socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);


private:
  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
      std::cout<<"handle read: bytes_transferred"<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;
    if (!error)
    {
          data_ = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
          /*read_handler(error, bytes_transferred);
          boost::asio::async_write(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error));*/
          boost::system::error_code ec;
          boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket_.remote_endpoint(ec);
          std::cout<<"ip address: "<<endpoint.address()<<std::endl;
          std::cout<<"port: "<<endpoint.port()<<std::endl;
          //how to get the socket to send data to specific port, ip-address e.g. changing the ip-address and port by editing it?
          async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), boost::bind(&session::writeHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }
  void writeHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, size_t bytesTransferred)
  {
        std::cout << "DEBUG> Transfered " << bytesTransferred << " bytes to " << socket_.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
  }
  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
      std::cout<<"handle write: "<<std::endl;

    if (!error)
    {
            std::cout<<"before: "<<data_<<std::endl;

            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

            std::cout<<"after: "<<data_<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};
void session::read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
      std::cout<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;
}

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    start_accept();
  }


private:
  void start_accept()
  {
    session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session* new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
    }
    else
    {
      delete new_session;
    }

    start_accept();
  }

  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server s(io_service, 4000);

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to apply some concepts of UDP to a TCP stream.

TCP needs to establish a connection with a 3-way handshake. 
For that reason, you can't send data to another client simply by modifying the ip remote endpoint address of a socket.

A TCP server listens for incoming connections, accepts them and at the end of this process has a valid TCP socket where you can write data. Each client has it's own socket. Also note that a TCP socket provides a data stream (not packets/datagrams).

On the other hand, UDP does not have the concept of a connection. You can send datagrams to multiple endpoints using the same UDP socket (boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::send_to)

Comment: If a TCP connection is made between the client(s) and the server isn't there some list on the server side that keeps track of the clients connected to it and can't that be accessed somehow to find a specific client?

Comment: The sample code you used as a template doesn't keep track of clients (in this case "session" instances). If you need a list of clients connected to the servers, you would typically build it while accepting the connection in the server class.

Comment: But then what object would I store about the clients when they connect?

Comment: The http server example in the boost documentation does that. Check connection_manager.hpp.

Comment: You mean this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/connection_manager.hpp it doesn't show much...

Comment: Yes I mean that example. That particular file shows that it stores a pointer to the instances representing the client connection in a std::set (in your case it would be a pointer to the `session` instances). Try to check the whole example to see how that works (Unfortunately that example is quite complex).

Comment: I know I'm looking at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/ and its daunting. So I just save the session instances and thats used to send packets how once I have them? Do I use the `async_write()` function as usual?

Comment: Check also this example, it's simpler: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/server.cpp